# Using dot (.) operator instead of -> operator C++

Tags: c++

Let's say I define a pointer structure called date_ptr of a structure already defined, the following way:

```
Date *date_ptr = new Date[10]
```

Essentially this is an array of structures containing objects of type Date. Now let's say I wanted to set the month of each structure in the array doing:

```
date_ptr[0].month = new int(10);
date_ptr[1].month = new int(3);
```

My question is as follows: am I allowed to set the month variable of each structure using the dot operator instead of the -> even though date_ptr is a pointer to the structure. If so, does this cause any problems? Or is it better (or mandatory) to use the -> operator?

Comment: If you were not - trust me the compiler would have err mentioned it

Answer (score 2):

In your case, data_ptr is a pointer, but data_ptr[0] is not a pointer, but a object of type Date. Thus you can only use dot (.) but not -> to access Date's fields.

Answer (score 1):

`date_ptr` is a pointer to structure but `date_ptr[0]` is a reference to a structure. That's because `date_ptr[0]` is the same as `*(date_ptr+0)`. So it's mandatory to use `.`.

Comment: What if "month" is defined as int *month? Then do I use the -> to reference date_ptr[0]?

Comment: The type of `month` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Careful, that's an array containing `0`s of type `Date *`. In particular, the following code will segfault without proper initialization.

Anyway to answer you, `->` is just syntactic sugar for equivalent code with `.`. You don't need to use it, you can simply write `date_ptr->month=0;` and it will compile. Or `(date_ptr+1)->month=0;` for the second element.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the following?  This would work.

```
Date * end_ptr = date_ptr + 10;
for (Date * ptr = date_ptr; ptr != end_ptr; ++ptr)
  ptr->month = 1;
```

Be warned not do do this if polymorphism is involved or you'll encounter a bad surprise.